# Download a File from the Download section of Bitbucket Repo using Access key

Tags: git, curl, bitbucket, wget

I'm looking for a way to download a file from bitbucket, (not the repository, a file from the download section). Currently, it is possible to clone a repository using a deployment key,  but I couldn't make it work for downloads.

I have tried the following:

`curl -u username: --key .ssh/id_rsa --pubkey .ssh/id_rsa.pub scp://bitbucket.org/repositoryowner/downloads/downloadfile.zip`

EDIT:

The current best workaround is to create a throw-away dummy user:

`wget -O /tmp/file --user "username" --password "password" https://bitbucket.org/owner/rep/downloads/abc.tar.gz`

Answer (score 8):

After a bunch of failed attempts, I received this response from Bitbucket support:

> Access keys in Bitbucket Cloud can be used for cloning or pulling from
>   a repository only, I'm afraid it is not possible to download files
>   from the Downloads section of the repo with SSH keys.
>
> Unless the repository is public, users will need to have a Bitbucket
>   Cloud account in order to authenticate and download files from the
>   Downloads page.
>
> Feel free to let us know if you have any further questions.

This has now been made a feature request on Bitbucket. If you want to have this functionality, then upvote it:

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/18501

Answer (score 0):

App password is another official workaround which works well.

First, you must generate an app password, here is the guide: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-an-app-password/

Then you can run a curl command:

```bash
curl --user {bitbucket_username}:{app_password} -L -O https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repository}/downloads/{filename}
```